# Is there a way to accept any string in a map variable?

Tags: terraform

I want to allow a map variable to accept any string (which would act like an "else") and have that string to something. Is there a way to do this?

```
variable "Branch" {
type = map
default = {
"example"  = "dev"

...

"any string" = "new branch"
...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The map alone can't do this, but you can use [the `try` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/try.html) in combination with a map to use a default value (rather than produce an error) if a particular element doesn't exist in the map:

```
try(var.branch["example"], "new branch")
```